# Faster algorithm for finding number of paths between two nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, nodes, graph-theory

I am trying to answer a question on an online judge in Python, but I am exceeding both the time limit and memory limit. The question is pretty much asking for the number of all paths from a start node to an end node. Full question specifications can be seen [here.](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc07s4)

This is my code:

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.read().strip().split('\n')
n = int(lines[0])
dict1 = {}

for i in xrange(1, n+1):
    dict1[i] = []

for i in xrange(1, len(lines) - 1):
    numbers = map(int, lines[i].split())
    num1 = numbers[0]
    num2 = numbers[1]
    dict1[num2].append(num1)

def pathfinder(start, graph, count):
    new = []
    if start == []:
        return count
    for i in start:
        numList = graph[i]
        for j in numList:
            if j == 1:
                count += 1
            else:
                new.append(j)

    return pathfinder(new, graph, count)   

print pathfinder([n], dict1, 0)
```

What the code does is it starts at the end node, and works its way up to the top by exploring all neighboring nodes. I made essentially a breadth first search algorithm, but its taking up too much space and time. How can I improve this code to make it more efficient? Is my approach wrong and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the graph is acyclic there is a topological ordering which we can immediately see to be `1, 2, ..., n`. So we can use dynamic programming the same way it is used to solve the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths). In a list `paths` the element `paths[i]` stores how many paths would there be from `1` to `i`. The update would be simple - for each edge `(i,j)` where `i` is from our topological order we do `paths[j] += path[i]`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(list)
n = int(input())
while True:
    tokens = input().split()
    a, b = int(tokens[0]), int(tokens[1])
    if a == 0:
        break
    graph[a].append(b)

paths = [0] * (n+1)
paths[1] = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in graph[i]:
        paths[j] += paths[i]
print(paths[n])
```

Note that what you are implementing is not actually `BFS` since you don't mark which vertices you've visited making your `start` to grow out of proportion.

Test the graph

```
for i in range(1, n+1):
    dict1[i] = list(range(i-1, 0, -1))
```

If you print the size of `start` you can see that the max value it gets for a given `n` grows exactly as  [binomial(n, floor(n/2))](https://oeis.org/A001405) which is ~4^n/sqrt(n). Note also that `BFS` is not what you want since it is not possible to count the number of paths in that way.

Comment: The code works, but I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly. For each node, the count is equal to the amount of times it was accessed by a parent node, accessed by each of its parents nodes, all the way up to 1? This would be done in O(vertices + edges) time?

Comment: @BobMarshall exactly!

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def build_matrix(filename, x):
    # A[i] stores number of paths from node x to node i.

    # O(n) to build parents_of_node
    parents_of_node = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as infile:
        num_nodes = int(infile.readline())
        A = [0] * (num_nodes + 1)  # A[0] is dummy variable. Not used.
        for line in infile:
            if line == "0 0":
                break

            u, v = map(int, line.strip().split())
            parents_of_node[v].append(u)

            # Initialize all direct descendants of x to 1
            if u == x:
                A[v] = 1

    # Number of paths from x to i = sum(number of paths from x to parent of i)
    for i in xrange(1, num_nodes + 1):  # O(n)
        A[i] += sum(A[p] for p in parents_of_node[i])  # O(max fan-in of graph), assuming O(1) for accessing dict.

    # Total time complexity to build A is O(n * (max_fan-in of graph))
    return A


def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]

    x = 1  # Find number of paths from x
    y = 4  # to y

    A = build_matrix(filename, x)
    print(A[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a DFS (not a BFS) in that code...

Here's a link to a good solution...
EDITED: 
Use this approach instead...

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/

Comment: SO tends to prefer unabridged answers which can be evaluated independent of external resources.